# Symfony fixture with php code inserts only one last record

Tags: symfony1, yaml, fixtures

My problem is that symfony propel:data-load feature creates only one DB record with id=20 (last one). this is weird, considering that such a fixture should iterate through the table, adding multiple records.

Here is my .yml file:

```
<?php for ($i = 10; $i <= 20; $i++): ?>
DocumentType:
  type_<?php echo $i?>:
  name: <?php echo "type ".$i."\n" ?>
<?php endfor ?>
```

And DB table has only 2 fields:

```
id int PK AI
name varchar
```

Answer (score 2):

your iteration creates this:

```
DocumentType:
    type_10:
        name: "type 10"
DocumentType:
    type_11:
        name: "type 11"
# ...
```

But you need:

```
DocumentType:
    type_10:
        name: "type 10"
    type_11:
        name: "type 11"
```

So you need to declare the class just one time.

Hope that helps!